# Python Iterating 2D Array, Return Array Value

Tags: arrays, numpy, iteration

I have created a 2D 10x10 Array. using Numpy I want to iterate over the array as efficiently as possible.

However I would like to return the array values. essentially iterating over the 10x10 array 10 times and return a 1x10 array each time.

```
 import datetime
 import numpy as np
 import random

 start = datetime.datetime.now()
 a = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10,10))
 print("Time :",datetime.datetime.now() - start)

 for x in np.nditer(a):
    print(x)
```

the result is as follows:

```
0.5738994777717537
0.24988408410910767
0.8391827831682657
0.0015975845830569213
0.54477459840569
0.14091622639476165
-0.36517132895234106
-0.06311125453484467
-0.6572544506539948

...

100 times
```

However I would expect the result to be:

```
[0.5738994777717537,
0.24988408410910767,
0.8391827831682657,
0.0015975845830569213,
0.54477459840569,
0.14091622639476165,
-0.36517132895234106,
-0.06311125453484467,
-0.6572544506539948],[...]

...

10 times
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First, why are  you using `nditer`?  What documentation are you working from?  Why not just `x.tolist()`?  Or `for x in a: print(x)`?  `nditer` effectively flattens the array, providing each value without regard to the `row/column` structure.  That should be obvious from the `nditer` documentation.  Also `nditer`, at least when called from Python, is not a speed tool.  It is not faster than simple iteration.

Comment: Efficient and iterate don't belong together when talking about `numpy` arrays.  Focus on using the fast compiled whole-array methods, not iteration.

Comment: You are just interested in slicing. Don't try to iterate, just have a look at [numpy slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). You are just looking for `a[0], a[1]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, this does exactly what you want:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10,10))
print(','.join([str(list(x)) for x in a]))
```

This will print

```
[-0.2403881196886386, ... , 0.8518165986395723],[-0.2403881196886386, ... , 0.8518165986395723], ..., [-0.2403881196886386, ... , 0.8518165986395723]
```

The reason you're printing just the elements of the array is due to the way `nditer` works. `nditer` iterates over single elements, even at a multidimensional level, whereas you want to iterate over just the first dimension of the array. For that, `for x in a:` works as intended.

## Edit

Here is a good link if you want to read up on how `nditer` works: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#arrays-nditer

Comment: That indexing reference is not very useful unless you read all the way to end, and start working in `cython`.